# Rest API Localization - Headers vs Payload

Tags: rest

We have one POST API live in production. Now we have a requirement to accept Localization information and proceed with execution accordingly.
e.g. if distanceUnit is "KM" then process all incoming data in Kilometers.

There are three options I could think of to accept localization information.

1. As a http header i.e. localization: {"distanceUnit": "km"}
2. As a part of payload itself.
3. Request parameter.

I like the 1st option as

- it doesn't change api contract.
- It's easier for other apis to send this info in case they need to be localized in future.
- Localization is a part of content negotiation so I don't think it should be part of payload/query parameter.

Any opinions here would be helpful to zero in on 1st or second option.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Localization for REST APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946136/localization-for-rest-apis)

Answer (score 1):

While `accept-language`, as indicated by the proposed link Kit posted, may be attempting, this only supports [registered languages](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry), maintained by IANA, the standadization gremium of the Web, but not certain generic configuration options out of the box. It may be attempting to default to `miles` for i.e. `Accept-Language: us` and use `km` elsewhere, American scientists may have certain issues with your application then if they want to use `km` instead of `miles`. But if this might not be the case, this clearly could be an option you might consider. In regards to custom HTTP headers, I wouldn't recommend using those as the problem with custom HTTP headers in general is that arbitrary generic HTTP clients do not support these which somehow contradicts the idea why one should use a REST architecture.

Let us transfer your problem to the Web domain for a second and see how we usually solve that task there. As REST is basically just a generalized approach to the common way we humans interact with the Web, any concepts used on the Web also apply to a REST architecture. Thus, designing the whole interaction flow as if your application interacts on a typical Web page is just common practice (or at least should be).

On the Web a so called [Web form](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html) is used to "teach" a Web client (a.k.a. Browser) what data the server expects as input. It not only teaches the client about the respective properties the server either expects or supports for a certain resource but also which HTTP method to use, about the target URI to send the request to and about the media-type to use, which implicitly is often just given as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but may also be `multipart/form-data`.

The usage of forms and links fall into the HATEOAS constraint where these concpets allow clients to progress through their task, i.e. of buying an item in a Web shop or administrating users in a system, without the need of ever having to consult an external documentation at all. Applications here basically just use the build-in hypermedia capabilities to progress through their tasks. Clients usually follow some kind of [predefined processes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=779s) where the server instructs clients on what they need to do in order to add an item to the shopping cart or on how to add or edit a user while still just operating on a generic HTML document that by itself isn't tailored to the respective task at hands. This approach allows Web clients to basically render all kinds of pages and users to interact with those generic pages. If something in that page representation changes your browser will automatically adept and render the new version on the next request. Hence, the system is able to evolve over time and adapt to changes easily. This is probably one of the core reasons why anyone wants to use a REST architecture basically.

So, back to the topic. On the Web a server would advertise to a client that it supports various localization information with above mentioned forms. A user might be presented a choice or dropdown option where s/he can select the appropriate option. The user usually does not care how this input is transferred to the server or about the internals of the server at all. All s/he cares for is that the data will be available after the request was submitted (in case of adding or updating a resource). This also holds true for application in a REST architecture.

You might see a pattern here. REST and the browsable Web are basically the same thing. The latter though focuses on human interaction while the primer one should allow applications to "surf the Web" and [follow allong processes outlined by the server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=534s) (semi-)automatically. As such it should be clear by now that the same concepts that apply to the browsable Web also apply to REST and applications in that REST architecture.

> I like the 1st option as ... it doesn't change api contract

Clients shouldn't bind to a particular API as this creates coupling, which REST tries to avoid at all costs. Instead of directly binding to an API, the Web and as such also REST should use [contracts build on hyper media types](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=843s) that define the admissible syntax and semantics of messages exchanged. By abstracting the contract away from the API itself to the media-type a client can support various contracts simultaneously. The generalization of the media-type furthermore allows to i.e. express various different things with the same media type and thus increase the likelihood for reusage and thus a better integration support into application layers.

Supporting various media-types is similar to speaking different languages. By being able to speak various languages you just increase the likelihood that you will be able to communicate with other people (services) out of the box without the need of learning those languages before. A client can tell a server via the `Accept` header which media-types it is able to "speak( (a.k.a. process) and the server will either respond with either of these or respond with a `406 Not Acceptable`. That error response is, as Jim Webber put it, [coordination data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=1046s) that at all times tells you whether everything went well or in case of failures gives you feedback on what went wrong.

In order to stay future-proof I therefore would suggest to design the configuration around hypertext enabled media types that support forms, i.e. HTML forms, [applicaiton/hal-forms+json](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/) or [application/ion+json](https://ionspec.org/#forms). If in future you need to add further configuration options adding these is just a trivial task. Whether that configuration is exposed as own resource which you just link to, as embedded part within the resource or not return to the client at all is also a choice you have. If the same configuration may be used by multiple resources it would be benefitial to expose it as own resource and then just create a reference from the resource to that configuration but as mentioned these are design decisions you have to make.

Answer (score 0):

If the POST request body is the only place where this is used, and you never have to do `GET` requests and automatically apply any conversion, my preference would probably go to adding it to the body.

It's nice to have a full document that contains all the information to describe itself, without requiring external out-of-band data to fully interpret its meaning.

You might like to define your schema to always include the unit in relevant parts of the document, for example:

```
distance: [5, 'km']
```

or, as you said, do it once at the top of the doc.